# Get distinct elements from a Rails ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a query in Rails like this:

```
@addresses=People.select("first_name, state").where("first_name = 'Bob'")
```

Is there a way I can iterate over addresses and pull out the distinct states, so that I know in which states someone named bob lives?

I'm trying to avoid:

```
@states = []
@address.each.do |add|
  if !@states.contains?(add.state)
    @states.push add
```

That just seems like bad form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@states = People.where(first_name: 'Bob').uniq.pluck(:state)
```

Comment: So it's best just to rerun a db query?

Comment: The return type -- an array of unique states. You wanted to "pull out the distinct states". That's exactly what the code does.