# Date search fails when nested association included with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, ransack

I have 2 models Person and Address with a has and belongs to many join table association.

Using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack).

When filtering on Date field, the first page is filtered correctly. When I click on any of the other paginations link, query changes from `date(persons.dob) >= '2013-09-01')` to `date(persons.dob) >= 2013)`

```
class Person
  has_many :person_addresses
  has_many :addresses, through: :person_addresses
end

class Address
  has_many :person_addresses
  has_many :persons, through: :person_addresses
end

class PersonAddress
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :address
end
```

Persons' search form has `dob_gteq`, `dob_lteq`, `name_cont` and `addresses.street_cont` filters.

If I filter on `dob_gteq` only, the first page works correctly. All other paginations causes:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: date >= integer
 LINE 1: ...name" WHERE ((date(persons.dob) >= 2013 AN...
```

Removing the `addresses.street_cont` filter from the search form allows it to work correctly and paginate as expected.

---

EDIT as requested controller action

```
@q = Person.search(params[:q])
@persons = @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

EDIT 2

Params coming in to search:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"", "addresses_street_cont"=>"", "addresses_zipcode_cont"=>"", "dob_gteq"=>"09-01-2013", "dob_lteq"=>""}, "commit"=>"Filter"}
```

Comment: Can you actually post the controller code that's generating this error?

Comment: Done as requested, but its pretty standard.

Comment: Both "search" and "result" methods are alien to me...is 'search' a method within the Person class that you haven't shown me? Why use result(:distinct => true) when you can use uniq? What version of RoR are you using?  I'd gander that "operator does not exist: date >= integer" means that there's a comparison between a date object and an integer object...dates compare to dates.  MOST importantly, where is the stack trace pointing to when the error is reported???  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130818/get-distinct-elements-from-a-rails-activerecord-query

Comment: I'm sorry, should have posted links.  Using will_paginate gem from https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate and ransack https://github.com/ernie/ransack.  "search" is a ransack method.  Updating error now.

Comment: OK...let's clear up your models, first. Do you need has_many :through, or just has_and_belongs_to_many? If your're not doing anything with PersonsAddress except for storing the link between Person and Address, just use has_and_belongs_to_many.  Take out your has_many declarations in each model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780798/has-and-belongs-to-many-vs-has-many-through

Comment: Also, now that I think about it...you need to check what the field persons.dob is giving to the params. How is it populated in the form? You basically need to also post your view.

Comment: to answer the first, unfortunately I do need the join.  Person can have more than 1 address and an address can have more than 1 person associated with it.  For the second, I posted the actual params being passed in to the controller, easier to read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39790/discussion-between-jakethesnake-and-pcasa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, changing the column from a datetime to a date, which fits better, solved my problem.